# Вывод набора данных из БД MySQL в таблицу на странице Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть таблица MySQL 'total_price'
В таблице есть столбцы 'gorod', 'tovar', 'price', 'date'
В столбце 'gorod' - идут города.
В столбце 'tovar' - ограниченный список товаров.
В столбце 'price' - цены на товар.
В столбце 'date' - дата совершения покупки.

Из разных городов люди покупают товар. В каждом городе на один и тот же товар могут быть разные цены.
К примеру в Москве купили печенье по 10 рублей, в Питере эти же печенья купили по 12 рублей.
Надо вывести данные из БД в две таблички на сайте в Wordpress (!!!).

Таблица 1: Средние цены по всем городам

```
  Товар     |   Цена вчера   |  Цена за 30 дней 
------------+----------------+-----------------
Печенье     |      11,25     |        12 
------------+----------------+-----------------
Конфеты     |       15,47    |      14,32
```

Т.е. тут выводится средняя цена за вчерашний день по каждому наименованию по всем городам из БД и средняя цена за 30 последних дней. Нужна именно средняя цена за все 30 дней по каждой позиции.

Вторая таблица точно такая же, но только нужно выбрать данные для конкретно одного города.

Я могу сделать отдельные SQL запросы через РНР. Например, Вывести в список все товары одного города. Или один товар по всем городам. Могу найти среднюю сумму по всему столбцу цены. Пока еще не научился делать сложные выборки, ну чтобы по одному городу выбрать только один товар и найти среднюю цену за 30 дней.
Могу РНР код вставить в страницу через шорткоды, но не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы результат запросов был виден на странице.

```
<?php 
require 'connect.php';  //обработчик к доступу БД с логином, паролем и т.п. 
global $wpdb;   
    $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM `total_price` WHERE `gorod`='Moscow'");
?>
```

Вот это вставляю через шорт код. Страница обрабатывается без ошибок. Понимаю, что вывод на экран делается через echo, могу указывать статичный текст, но что в него вбивать для данных из БД еще не врубаюсь.

Comment: Нда.. жесть.. Но кури https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с SQL запросами.
Создал промежуточную таблицу `moscowprices` идентичную первоначальной, но добавил столбцы для цен за определенный период (Цена вчера, средняя за семь дней, за месяц, три месяца, полгода и год). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица заполняется SQL запросами из РНР файла. Запросы кидают средние значения в промежуточную таблицу. При этом во время расчета среднего значения исключаются строки с нулевым значением. Чтобы расчет среднего значения шел среди позиций с суммами. В конце просто суммирую все столбцы с отбором по строкам. Если к числу прибавить ноль, то мы все равно получаем то же самое число, а в моих выборках в принципе не может быть в одном столбце у одного товара двух и более значений больше нуля. Всегда будет одно значение >0, все остальные будут нули. Это нужно для того, чтобы в таблице не было дубликатов строк с нулями. Не знаю на сколько это грамотный подход, главное, что он работает.

```
<?php 
require 'scripts/connect.php';

$wpdb->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `moscowprices`", $conn);  // предварительно удаляем данные в таблице

?>

<?php

//заполняем промежуточную таблицу
$wpdb->query("
INSERT INTO `moscowprices`(gorod, tovar, PriceE)
SELECT `gorod`, `tovar`, ROUND (AVG(price),2) AS 'PriceE' FROM `total_price` WHERE `gorod`='moscow' AND `price` >0 AND (`date` = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) GROUP BY `tovar`
", $conn ) ;

$wpdb->query("
INSERT INTO `moscowprices`(gorod, tovar, Pricesevenday)
SELECT `gorod`, `tovar`, ROUND (AVG(price),2) AS 'Pricesevenday' FROM `total_price` WHERE `gorod`='moscow' AND `price` >0 AND (`date` between DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and current_date()) GROUP BY `tovar` 
", $conn) ;

$wpdb->query("
INSERT INTO `moscowprices`(gorod, tovar, Pricemonth)
SELECT `gorod`, `tovar`, ROUND (AVG(price),2) AS 'Pricemonth' FROM `total_price` WHERE `gorod`='moscow' AND `price` >0 AND (`date` between DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and current_date()) GROUP BY `tovar` 
", $conn) ;

$wpdb->query("
INSERT INTO `moscowprices`(gorod, tovar, Pricethreemonth)
SELECT `gorod`, `tovar`, ROUND (AVG(price),2) AS 'Pricethreemonth' FROM `total_price` WHERE `gorod`='moscow' AND `price` >0 AND (`date` between DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) and DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)) GROUP BY `tovar` 
", $conn) ;

$wpdb->query("
INSERT INTO `moscowprices`(gorod, tovar, Pricehalfyear)
SELECT `gorod`, `tovar`, ROUND (AVG(price),2) AS 'Pricehalfyear' FROM `total_price` WHERE `gorod`='moscow' AND `price` >0 AND (`date` between DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 180 DAY) and DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 150 DAY)) GROUP BY `tovar` 
 ", $conn) ;

$wpdb->query("
INSERT INTO `moscowprices`(gorod, tovar, Priceyear)
SELECT `gorod`, `tovar`, ROUND (AVG(price),2) AS 'Priceyear' FROM `total_price` WHERE `gorod`='moscow' AND `price` >0 AND (`date` between DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) and DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 335 DAY)) GROUP BY `tovar` 
 ", $conn);

?>

<?php
//суммируем все столбцы и выводим готовую таблицу на странице сайта.
$items = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT `tovar`, SUM(`PriceE`) AS `PriceE`, SUM(`Pricesevenday`) AS `Pricesevenday`, SUM(`Pricemonth`) AS `Pricemonth`, SUM(`Pricethreemonth`) AS `Pricethreemonth`, SUM(`Pricehalfyear`) AS `Pricehalfyear`, SUM(`Priceyear`) AS `Priceyear` FROM `moscowprices` GROUP BY `tovar`


" );

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
       echo "<p> $item->tovar - $item->PriceE - $item->Pricesevenday - $item->Pricemonth- $item->Pricethreemonth- $item->Pricehalfyear - $item->Priceyear</p>";
    }


   mysqli_close($conn);

?>
введите сюда код
```